# List Index Out Of Bounds

Tags: c#, android

I am trying to retrieve one value from a combo box and place it into another combo box by using lists.

I successfully remove the value from the list, and implement it into the other list fine. But when I do this my list capacities malfunction and I get index out of bounds errors.

Scenario:

> List Letter Selected: B
>
> 'Left Shift Button Pressed'
>
> 'B' Removed from Letters List
>
> 'B' Added to Numbers List
>
> Print Out Values
>
> Error: "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of collection
>
> Line 66: Console.WriteLine("Numbers: " + numbers[i] + "\tIteration: " + i);
>
> Number List Capacity: 8, Letters List Capacity: 4.
>
> Number List: 1, 2, 3, 4, B. Letters List: A, C, D

CODE:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public List<string> letters = new List<string>();
    public List<string> numbers = new List<string>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InitialiseLists();
        LoadListsIntoCombo();
    }

    public void InitialiseLists()
    {
        /*
         * Add Letter Data
         */
        letters.Add("A");
        letters.Add("B");
        letters.Add("C");
        letters.Add("D");

        /*
         * Add Number Data
         */
        numbers.Add("1");
        numbers.Add("2");
        numbers.Add("3");
        numbers.Add("4");

    }

    public void LoadListsIntoCombo()
    {

        comboLetter.DataSource = letters;
        comboNumber.DataSource = numbers;

    }

    public void PrintList()
    {
        /*
         * Print Lists To Console
         */
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Capacity; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("NUM CAPACITY: " + numbers.Capacity);
            Console.WriteLine("Numbers: " + numbers[i] + "\tIteration: " + i);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < letters.Capacity; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("LET CAPACITY: " + letters.Capacity);
            Console.WriteLine("Letters : " + letters[i] + "\tIteration: " + i);

        }

    }


    private void cmdLeft_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        AddLetterToNumber(GetLetter());
        RemoveLetter(GetLetter());

    }

    public void RemoveLetter(string value)
    {
        letters.Remove(value);
    }

    public void AddLetterToNumber(string value)
    {
        numbers.Add(value);
    }

    public string GetLetter()
    {
        string letter = comboLetter.SelectedItem.ToString();
        return letter;
    }

    public int GetLetterIndex()
    {
        int letterIndex = comboLetter.SelectedIndex;

        return letterIndex;
    }

    private void cmdRight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrintList();
    }

}

    }
```

Many thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 5):

Use [Count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3.aspx) property instead of [`Capacity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y52x03h2.aspx). Because first one returns number of items contained in list. Second one is just says how many items you can add before list will be resized.

```
public void PrintList()
{
   Console.WriteLine("Numbers count: " + numbers.Count);    
   for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Count; i++)   
       Console.WriteLine("Numbers: {0}\tIteration: {1}", numbers[i], i);       

   Console.WriteLine("Letters count: " + letters.Count);    
   for (int i = 0; i < letters.Count; i++)       
       Console.WriteLine("Letters : {0}\tIteration: {1}", letters[i], i);   
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for such a quick reply - appreciate it. Will accept after time limit.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I moved total count displaying out of loop. But `for` loop is good here since OP wants index to be displayed

Comment: OP could use a `foreach` and an additional counter to display the # of iteration, but yes the `for` can do this job :).

Answer (score 1):

You are using Capacity and not Count.  Capacity is not the number of elements in the list.

```
    Capacity: Gets or sets the total number of elements the internal data structure can hold without resizing.
    Count: Gets the number of elements actually contained in the List<T>.
```

from here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your reply and explanation, appreciate it.